# Dimmable LED bulb

Tags: lighting, smart-lights

I am redesigning our bathroom and currently looking at two different light sources

- 12V LED spots with a dimmable LED driver (via 1kHz PWM)
- Some sort of chandelier with a E27 (bulb).

I want the bulb also to be dimmable. I found [this](https://at.rs-online.com/web/p/gls-led-lampen/1235908?cm_mmc=AT-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_AT_DE_Beleuchtung_Whoop_HI-_-(AT:Whoop!)%20GLS%20LED-%20Lampen-_-PRODUCT_GROUP&matchtype=&aud-826607888547:pla-333414383946&gclid=CjwKCAiAy9jyBRA6EiwAeclQhD9DlI0DVNNIUtTUnt1RwW-xA1QLxWSKrDxiBBeDUmoYznOSyM3RMRoCbNUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) bulb, which needs a classic triac dimmer. Since I want to control the lights using a self build controller (based on the SAM51J) I do not know the correct approach.

I was looking for dimmable 12V bulbs but was not able to find anything commercial. Either they are dimmable with a LED-driver or via "Smart"-Bulbs (zigbee or similar).

Is there a bulb with E27 which I can dim over a 12V LED-Driver?

Comment: Hi, you can ask this question for a better response in [Hardware Recommendation](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I found a solution, which also changed the design:

- There are some 24V-Led Bulbs (even for E14) available in most LED electronics shops online (even on A****n)
- As LED-driver I will use the DALI protocol with its special drivers. In my case with constant voltage
- As control unit there are DALI masters available in said shops. Schematics for DALI masters are also available online (for [Arduino](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/NabiyevTR/simple-dali-controller-506e44), [standalone](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/AP0810414_LightNet.pdf?fileId=db3a304329a0f6ee0129c69b34482e9c))